# Is there any REST API which can give information about validators on status while changing status in JIRA?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api

In JIRA, we can give validators while changing the status. Example : Open -> Start Progress, while changing status from open to Start Progress we can give one mandatory field "comments". So when user will change status to start progress, JIRA will ask for comment. Now I want to fetch this validator on this status change. So is there any way to get it using any API ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-1234/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```

Which will show the transitions available for the issue and within each transitions it will show a `fields` section which will detail if that field is required for example:

```
timetracking: {
   required: false,
   schema: {
      type: "timetracking",
      system: "timetracking"
   },
   name: "Time Tracking",
   operations: [
      "set",
      "edit"
   ]
}
```

Or:

```
resolution: {
    required: true,
    schema: {
        type: "resolution",
        system: "resolution"
    },
    name: "Resolution",
    operations: [
        "set"    
    ],
    allowedValues: [
        {
            self: "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/resolution/1",
            name: "Fixed",
            id: "1"
        },
        ...
        {
            self: "https://jira.atlassian.com/rest/api/2/resolution/18",
            name: "Support Request",
            id: "18"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I checked with one custom and one system field(comment). I marked both of them as required field using validators but response that I got using above REST request did not say anything about this mandatory field. Even their "required" attribute's value is "false".